# Build error with ClickOnce-Manifest in TFS Build

Tags: tfs, build, outlook, vsto

we try to build a .net vsto application on our buildserver.

The project build with a click once build manifest.

It works on two developer machines, when the certificate is installed. In build machine it doesn´t work:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3090,5): Error MSB3326: Die folgende Schlüsseldatei kann nicht importiert werden: . Die Schlüsseldatei ist möglicherweise kennwortgeschützt. Importieren Sie das Zertifikat erneut, oder importieren Sie das Zertifikat manuell in den persönlichen Zertifikatspeicher des aktuellen Benutzers, um das Problem zu beheben.

EN:
error MSB3326: Cannot import the following key file: . The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or import the certificate manually into the current user's personal certificate store. [C:...csproj]

The certificate is installed on build machine.

Has anybody some idea how can I solve the problem?

Best regards

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution in [this case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/cc7a38fc-dde0-4280-815c-cdd6ddbd992d/the-key-file-may-be-password-protected-to-correct-this-try-to-import-the-certificate-again-or?forum=tfsbuild):

Login build agent machine using a build service account, **open Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017** and **cd to …\src\solutionname\projectname folder**, then run `sn -i xx.pfx VS_KEY_xxx` and type password, after it is imported completely, close this Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017.